# Random Forest yields insanely OOB high error rates

Tags: r, random-forest

I am using randomForestSRC to fit a random forest of 1000 trees for a 3-class classification problem with 160 cases. I am observing insanely high OOB error rates, sometimes as high as 75%, which is worse than guessing. What could be causing this? My calls are of the form

```
rfsrc(formula, data=df, block.size=1, ntree=1000, importance=TRUE,  verbose=FALSE, splitrule="auc", nsplit=NULL, nodesize=1)
```

Comment: Your categories may be poorly described by your data, try a different algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

How many features does your input data have? Given that you only have a 160 cases this looks like it could be over-fitting. 
PS: This should be more useful as a comment but I cannot post any yet

Comment: Anywhere from 5 to a couple of dozen, but even the 5 case has an OOB error of 0.7.

Comment: Are you using sensitive data? If you're not, and you're happy to share I'll try it on my end, see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the offer! It is highly sensitive patient data, unfortunately.